# Open app in android from different app with link: googlechrome://navigate?url=https://www.exampleA.com

Tags: android, google-chrome, uri, applinks, deeplink

I have an app called example A. I have installed app links successfullly. I can click link on google chrome browser to open app Example A with deep link: https://www.exampleA.com.

I want open app Example A from different app (Example B). If app B returns link: https://www.exampleA.com, app A will be opened. 
But app Example B returns: googlechrome://navigate?url=https://www.exampleA.com/.
When it runs, it will open google chrome browser with url: https://www.exampleA.com

I want App B will call App Example A to open.

Can you provide me a solution or keyword to solve my issue? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Unclear why Example B app doesn't use explicit intent to open Example A app or use ACTION_VIEW intent with Chrome package to open www.exampleA.com site in browser.

Comment: I suppose App B is a 3rd-party app, and he wants to filter in all intents having exampleA urls, even if App B explicitly intends to use Google Chrome.

Comment: Yes, App B is a 3rt-party app

Comment: If App B intends to use Google Chrome, attempting to intercept is breaking the intent contract, if App B just asks to show Site A without explicit browser package, then intent filter rules apply. Perhaps if App B used [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) the behavior could be approached.